# Mysql: impossible where noticed after reading const tables

Tags: mysql

i have one query:

```
SELECT l.id, title 
FROM (SELECT id 
      FROM news 
      WHERE (title LIKE '%football predictions argentina%' OR text LIKE '%football predictions argentina%') 
             AND lang = 'en' 
             AND STATUS = 1 
      ORDER BY id LIMIT 0, 10)  
o JOIN news l ON l.id = o.id 
WHERE 1 
ORDER BY date DESC 
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

which by the explain command is giving me: impossible where noticed after reading const tables

unfortunately i cannot figure out, what that means and how to fix it ?

the structure of the table is like this:

```
id      int(10) 
title   varchar(255)    
text    text    
image   varchar(255)    
lang    varchar(3)  
date    date    
status  smallint(1)
```

and except the id - Primary key i have one combined index on (lang, status, date)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

"impossible where noticed after reading const tables" is bit confusing message. It basically means that one of your where criteria did not match any records, therefore the MySQL optimiser could not (did not want to...) proceed with analysing the query further. It just simply returns an empty resultset.

Fix is very simple: make sure you test the explain with such where clauses that do return resultset.

MySQL has an open [feature request](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=64197) asking to change the message to a more meaningful one, but I do not think they ever have bothered.

Comment: Thank you @Shadow !

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Shadow's answer, MySQL's explain will show: 
 `Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables`

 when a where condition on a non-indexed field is not matched along with a matched where condition on an indexed field.

It will show 
`no matching row in const table`
when a where condition on an indexed field is not matched.